# Frederic Schuller lecture notes

Tags: statistical-mechanics, specific-reference

I saw that Frederic Schuller gave a lecture on statistical physics almost 10 years ago. Does anyone have the corresponding lecture notes? Unfortunately, the link
https://eswirdeinskriptgeben.wordpress.com/2013/02/02/statistische-physik_fpschuller/
no longer works.

Comment: You can try, but I don't know anyone who has received an answer to an email. Moreover, the lecture notes are mostly transcripts from students and not from Frederic Schuller.

Comment: No, but thanks to a few contacts I was able to get the lecture notes elsewhere. If you want it, I should warn you that it is in German and the quality is not on the same level as the other lecture notes. It is also a transcript and therefore contains some errors and missing parts.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4bh941e0vo95tj/Stat.%20Mechanik.pdf?dl=0